# stack operation using c language

Tags: c, struct, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, declaration

can anyone help me why this code is not working?
this code is not showing any output nor any error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    int* arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack* ptr) {
    if (ptr->top == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack* s;
    s->size = 5;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int*)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    if (isEmpty(s)) {
        printf("Stack is Empty.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Stack is not Empty");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help me why this code is not working?

Comment: You need to allocate memory to the structure pointer `*s` before you can assign values to its members. Use `struct stack *s; s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`

Comment: I wonder why you didn't encounter any error

Comment: @GauravPathak Undefined behavior is undefined ... anything can happen.

Comment: All of the major compilers warn you about this when you request elevated warnings, which should be your default. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: @GauravPathak: GCC and Clang do not warn about this by default. You have to request additional warnings.

Comment: Sorry for my quick comment, I wanted to ask why OP didn't get Seg Fault or runtime error

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was actually referring to a runtime error (that's what I thought GauravPathak was hinting towards). Dereferencing uninitiazlied `s` might [typically] cause an access violation error (seg-fault), but not necessarily as it is UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following lines:

```
struct stack* s;
s->size = 5;
s->top = -1;
s->arr = (int*)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));
```

By definition of the `->` operator, the line

```
s->size = 5;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*s).size = 5;
```

This means that your code is attempting to dereference the object pointed to by `s` and assign one of its members a value. For this to work, the pointer `s` must be pointing to a valid object. However, this is not the case. You never assigned a value to `s`, so it is most likely not pointing to a valid object.

In order to make `s` point to a valid object, you have several options. You could create a local variable and make `s` point to that object:

```
int main( void )
{
    struct stack object;

    struct stack *s = &object;
    s->size = 5;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = malloc( s->size * sizeof(int) );

    [...]
```

Or you could allocate the necessary memory using `malloc` and make `s` point to that memory:

```
int main( void )
{
    struct stack *s = malloc( sizeof *s );
    s->size = 5;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = malloc( s->size * sizeof(int) );

    [...]
```

Or you may want to make `s` not a pointer, but a normal object:

```
int main( void )
{
    struct stack s;
    s.size = 5;
    s.top = -1;
    s.arr = malloc( s->size * sizeof(int) );

    [...]
```

In contrast to C++, in C, it is not necessary ([and also not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/12149471)) to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Also, it is generally a good idea to check the return value of `malloc`, because otherwise, if `malloc` ever returns `NULL`, your program will likely crash. It would be better to exit with an error message, when `malloc` returns `NULL`, for example like this:

```
s.arr = malloc( s->size * sizeof(int) );
if ( s.arr == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Additionally, you should generally `free` the memory when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the uninitialized pointer `s` for accessing memory

```
struct stack* s;
s->size = 5;
s->top = -1;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You could allocate an object of the type `struct stack` dynamically and assign its address to the pointer `s`. But there is no great sense to allocate the object dynamically.

It is simpler to write

```
struct stack s = { 5, -1, malloc( 5 * sizeof(int) ) };
```

Then the function `isEmpty` that can also be defined simpler like

```
int isEmpty( const struct stack *ptr ) 
{
    return ptr->top == -1;
}
```

is called like

```
if ( isEmpty( &s ) ) {
```

When the stack will not be required any more you need to free the allocated memory for the integer array like

```
free( s.arr );
```

Pay attention to that it is much better to declare the structure stack using a unsigned integer type for the data members `size` and `top`. For example

```
struct stack 
{
    size_t size;
    size_t top;
    int *arr;
};
```

To allocate an object of the structure type dynamically you could write a separate function as for example

```
struct stack * create_stack( size_t size )
{
    struct stack &s = malloc( sizeof( *s ) );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        s->size = 0;
        s->top = 0;
        s->arr = NULL;

        if ( size != 0 )
        {
             s->arr = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
             if ( s->arr != NULL )
             {
                 s->size = size;
             }
             else
             {
                 free( s );
                 s = NULL;
             }
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

and in main you can write

```
struct stack *s = create_stack( 5 );
//...
```

In this case the function `isEmpty` will look like

```
int isEmpty( const struct stack *ptr ) 
{
    return ptr->top == 0;
}
```

and a similar function as for example `isFull` will look like

```
int isFull( const struct stack *ptr ) 
{
    return ptr->top == ptr->size;
}
```

The functions are called in main like

```
if ( isEmpty( s ) ) {
//...
```

and

```
if ( isFull( s ) ) {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make `s` not a pointer, so that the code would become as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    int* arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack ptr) {
    if (ptr.top == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack s;
    s.size = 5;
    s.top = -1;
    s.arr = malloc(s.size * sizeof(int));

    if (isEmpty(s)) {
        printf("Stack is Empty.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Stack is not Empty");
    }

    return 0;
}
```